# use jquery to change css values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, pseudo-element

I was trying to do this with pure CSS by using the `:focus` and `tabindex` method for interacting with `<div>`'s but when I tried to add a video through HTML it broke it all so I have had to resort to jQuery.

I'm new to JavaScript but what I'm trying to do is make it so when you click on the `#about_me.tab:before` element it moves the `#about_me.tab` to 0vh and changes its `z-index` to 5 and then alters the `box-shadow` but this isn't working can anyone see a problem or is it the HTML or CSS

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#about_me.tab:before").click(function(){
    $("#about_me.tab").css({"transition":"top 1s, z-index 0s","top":"0vh","z-index":"5","box-shadow":"0 0 8vw black"});
  });
});
</script>
```

Indy

Comment: What "isn't working"? Is it firing the click event handler? If not, your first selector is wrong, if it *is* firing - your second selector is wrong.

Comment: You can't select pseudo-element via jQuery/JS, because they are not in DOM.

Comment: have you considered reacting somehow on answers? :)

Answer (score 1):

You should use jQuery selector instead of using pseudo-elements:

```
 $("#about_me.tab").prev().click(function(){
    $("#about_me.tab").css({"transition":"top 1s, z-index 0s","top":"0vh","z-index":"5","box-shadow":"0 0 8vw black"});
 });
```

or

```
 $("#about_me.tab").click(function(){
    $("#about_me.tab").prev().css({"transition":"top 1s, z-index 0s","top":"0vh","z-index":"5","box-shadow":"0 0 8vw black"});
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

**jQuery**

```
$("#about_me.tab").addClass('shadow');
```

**CSS**

```
.shadow{
//Your style

}
```